# Loop in subplots - values in the plot are wrong

Tags: python, loops, subplot

I want to create a loop in several REGIONS that create 4 plot each one to each variable (AW00, AW10, AW15, AW20. I manage to get the subplots for each region but the values are wrong - please see the figure attached. Can anybody help me?
updated code below
[exmaple_plot_result_region_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuZes.png)

```
for region in dfall.ZoneID_00.unique():
    fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize = (10,6))
    dfall.plot(ax = ax1, title=region+" AW00", x="Factor_00", y=["P2015_00", "P2020_00", "P2025_00","P2030_00","P2035_00","P2040_00","P2045_00", "P2050_00"], legend=False)
    ax1.set_title(region + "AW 00")
    dfall.plot(ax = ax2, title=region+" AW10", x="Factor_00", y=["P2015_10", "P2020_10", "P2025_10","P2030_10","P2035_10","P2040_10","P2045_10", "P2050_10"], legend=False)
    ax2.set_title(region + "AW 10")
    dfall.plot(ax = ax3, title=region+" AW15", x="Factor_00", y=["P2015_15", "P2020_15", "P2025_15","P2030_15","P2035_15","P2040_15","P2045_15", "P2050_15"], legend=False)
    ax3.set_title(region + "AW 15")
    dfall.plot(ax = ax4, title=region+" AW20", x="Factor_00", y=["P2015_20", "P2020_20", "P2025_20","P2030_20","P2035_20","P2040_20","P2045_20", "P2050_20"], legend=False)
    ax4.set_title(region + "AW 20")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to help when you don't include a minimum reproducable example. For instance, I have to assume that you are using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, but that is in no way certain.

Assuming that, you are overwriting your `axes` variable with some kind of `dfall` variable, of which I cannot know anything. That is probably your main issue, but it also seems that you are trying to plot strings; `plot()` takes variable names without strings as arguments. Try removing the quotations marks around the variables, but keep them in the title argument.

That's as far as I can help you without more information, I'm afraid.

Comment: I have updated the code and added a picture of the results for one region. It could be something related to the different values of the variables.

Comment: It's still not a Minimal Reproducible Example. What is dfall?! What is its plot function? Please see this before asking for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example